# #if & #define В unity С#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно сделать так что если переменная true(в другом файле .cs) то компилировать код а если не true то не компилировать его вовсе как это сделать? В C++ было намного проще и понятнее чем в C#)

Comment: Не надо компилировать код, надо просто вызывать метод в зависимости от условия.

Comment: Директивы сборки задаются сборщику, а не в другом cs файле. Вы что-то перепутали.

Comment: `#define` в C++ - это макрос. `#define` в C# - определяет "символ", который используется только в директивах препроцессора. Условную компиляцию с его помощью можно сделать. Но его нельзя связать с переменной в коде.

Comment: Ваш файл с переменной может [менять директивы](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup.html) компиляции в зависимости от переменной, если очень хочется